# Building my own StreamTokenizer in java

Tags: java, regex

Hi there
I am building my own `StreamTokenizer` that would match my needs. 
Just like java's `StreamTokenizer`, I have a `nextToken()` method that returns an integer representing the type of data found. 
What I'm trying to do is that in case the token does not match any regex pattern I use, it would return the token itself as an integer code. For example the token '$' would result in returning a number such that println(number) would print $.
I have no idea how to do it, anyone?

thanks!

Comment: `return '$';` or `return (int)'$';` and then `println((char)number)` perhaps? If not, please explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: i'll try - when you use StreamTokenizer and the current token is not TT_NUMBER or TT_WORD you can switch (st.nextToken()) and have case '$': meaning it returns an integer representing the $ symbol

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a lexer from a bunch of regular expressions, look into parser generators like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Quick+Starter+on+Parser+Grammars+-+No+Past+Experience+Required).

If you really want to hand-roll your own, then you can always use the following idiom:

```
// Matches tokens foo and bar
Pattern myTokenDefinition = Pattern.compile("^(?:foo|bar)");

public boolean hasNext() {
  return sourceText.length() != 0;
}

public String next() {
  if (sourceText.length() != 0) {
    Matcher m = myTokenDefinition.matcher(sourceText);
    String token;
    if (m.find()) {
      token = m.group();
    } else {
      token = sourceText.substring(0, 1);
    }
    sourceText = sourceText.substring(token.length());
    return token;
  }
  throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```